# sample code for find coordinate using LAc, MNC, MCC, CID in c#

Tags: c#, geolocation, api-key

recently i'm doing some research on geolocation in c#.
not much information for me in the internet.
anyone can send me a link or a short sample code for this geolocation in c#.
i using visual studio 2010. use console application to do.
user input LAC, MCC, MNC, CID and also using google api key to find their location(long,lat).

really appreciate for helping me.

Comment: The app is running is what type of device? Does it has GPS? Does it has access to tower ID? Does it has access to public IP address?

Comment: sorry about that. i forget to put it in.. just normal desktop.now got so many app that can search for LAC, MCC, MNC, CID. i want user to input these data input my app so it can calculate the longitude and latitude for the data they have put.

Comment: Do you have an example of app that can calculate lat/long by LAC, MCC, MNC, CID? If you do not have a SIM card in desktop, how you are getting the LAC etcs information?

Answer (score 0):

Check below code You can get LAT LNG 
i hope this helpful :)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class GoogleMapsApi
    {
        static byte[] PostData(int MCC, int MNC, int LAC, int CID)
        {

        /* The shortCID parameter follows heuristic experiences:

         * Sometimes UMTS CIDs are build up from the original GSM CID (lower 4 hex digits)

         * and the RNC-ID left shifted into the upper 4 digits.

         */

        byte[] pd = new byte[] {

    0x00, 0x0e,

    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,

    0x00, 0x00,

    0x00, 0x00,

    0x00, 0x00,

    0x1b,

    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // Offset 0x11

    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // Offset 0x15

    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // Offset 0x19

    0x00, 0x00,

    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // Offset 0x1f

    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // Offset 0x23

    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // Offset 0x27

    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // Offset 0x2b

    0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff,

    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00

};
        Console.WriteLine(pd.Length);

        bool isUMTSCell = ((Int64)CID > 65535);

        /*    if (shortCID)

                CID &= 0xFFFF;      /* Attempt to resolve the cell using the

                            GSM CID part */

        if ((Int64)CID > 65536) /* GSM: 4 hex digits, UTMS: 6 hex

                        digits */

            pd[0x1c] = 5;

        else

            pd[0x1c] = 3;

        pd[0x11] = (byte)((MNC >> 24) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x12] = (byte)((MNC >> 16) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x13] = (byte)((MNC >> 8) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x14] = (byte)((MNC >> 0) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x15] = (byte)((MCC >> 24) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x16] = (byte)((MCC >> 16) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x17] = (byte)((MCC >> 8) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x18] = (byte)((MCC >> 0) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x27] = (byte)((MNC >> 24) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x28] = (byte)((MNC >> 16) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x29] = (byte)((MNC >> 8) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x2a] = (byte)((MNC >> 0) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x2b] = (byte)((MCC >> 24) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x2c] = (byte)((MCC >> 16) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x2d] = (byte)((MCC >> 8) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x2e] = (byte)((MCC >> 0) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x1f] = (byte)((CID >> 24) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x20] = (byte)((CID >> 16) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x21] = (byte)((CID >> 8) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x22] = (byte)((CID >> 0) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x23] = (byte)((LAC >> 24) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x24] = (byte)((LAC >> 16) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x25] = (byte)((LAC >> 8) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x26] = (byte)((LAC >> 0) & 0xFF);

        return pd;

    }

    static public string[] GetLatLng(int MCC, int MNC, int LAC, int CID)
    {

        string[] result = new string[2];

        try
        {

            String url = "http://www.google.com/glm/mmap";

            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(

                new Uri(url));

            req.Method = "POST";

            byte[] pd = PostData(MCC, MNC, LAC, CID);

            req.ContentLength = pd.Length;

            req.ContentType = "application/binary";

            Stream outputStream = req.GetRequestStream();

            outputStream.Write(pd, 0, pd.Length);

            outputStream.Close();

            HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

            byte[] ps = new byte[res.ContentLength];

            int totalBytesRead = 0;

            while (totalBytesRead < ps.Length)
            {

                totalBytesRead += res.GetResponseStream().Read(

                    ps, totalBytesRead, ps.Length - totalBytesRead);

            }

            //for(int i=0;i<ps.Length;i++)
            //    Console.WriteLine(ps[i]);
            string r = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ps);
            Console.WriteLine(r);



            if (res.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {

                short opcode1 = (short)(ps[0] << 8 | ps[1]);

                byte opcode2 = ps[2];

                int ret_code = (int)((ps[3] << 24) | (ps[4] << 16) |

                               (ps[5] << 8) | (ps[6]));

                if (ret_code == 0)
                {

                    double lat = ((double)((ps[7] << 24) | (ps[8] << 16)

                                 | (ps[9] << 8) | (ps[10]))) / 1000000;

                    double lon = ((double)((ps[11] << 24) | (ps[12] <<

                                 16) | (ps[13] << 8) | (ps[14]))) /

                                 1000000;

                    result[0] = lat.ToString();
                    result[1] = lon.ToString();
                    return result;

                }

                else
                {

                    return result;
                }

            }

            else

                return result;

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result[0] = ex.Message;
            return result;

        }

    }
}
}
```